# word spacing in fraction

Tags: spacing, fractions

I want to have 2 separate words in a fraction (numerator & denominator), however, LaTeX would keep them together with no space.

I'm using the `amsmath` package. And this is the line of the code:

```
\centering
$\frac {desired  displacement_{max}}{actual  displacement_{max}}
```

How can I keep (desired and displacement) separately?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add text in math mode, use the `\text` command provided by amsmath.

```
\frac{\text{foo bar}_{\text{max}}}{\text{foo bar}_{\text{min}}}
```

Comment: Since `\max` and `\min` are operators, they need not be placed in `\text` macros, as they will present in upright font already: `\frac{\text{foo bar}_{\max}}{\text{foo bar}_{\min}}`

Comment: I don’t think “max” and “min” are operator in this context but just indication that the values are the maximum and the minimum. It could have been superscript plus and minus as well.

Comment: It just saves some typing, that's all.

Comment: OK, I didn’t even think of this simple thing. However, wouldn’t the spacing around `\min` and `\max` be wrong, as operators always have some space around them?

Comment: @Zoxume no the spacing after a mathop is only added if there is something following. (but you should use \textrm not \text so that you get a fixed font not the font current outside the math (`\max` will use `\mathrm` so doesn't have that problem)